# How can I put a process to background after its execution with broken CTRL+Z?

Tags: background, stdout

*The question is special because some keys, such as CTRL+Z, stopped working.*

I tried to put the process to background by typing in the order:

> 1. find /
> 2. CTRL+Z
> 3. bg

However, I can still see the stdout. The only difference to only doing the first step is that the command CTRL+Z does not work anymore. It is rather nasty when I have unsaved jobs and my harddrive is over 100GB. So

> how can I put the process to background?

**[Details]**

I am using the fourth version of Bash on Mac.

**[Crux Reply by Nicholas Riley]**

The problem is really that I do not understand the "ramifications" of running process background. I cannot understand why the commnands, such as CTRL+Z, do not work to background processes. I was still able to kill the process in another shell with the command:

```
ps -ej | awk '! /grep/ && /find/ {print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`^Z` isn't working because the frontmost job is now the shell, and shells don't usually respond to `SIGTSTP`.  (If you do really want to suspend a non-login shell, `suspend` usually works.)

The problem seems to be you misunderstand the ramifications of a job being in the background.  Redirecting the job's standard output is unrelated.

In fact, it's unclear *what* you want to do.  If you just want to stop `find` from running, then `fg` it and use `^C` or `^\` (which by default send `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` respectively).

If you want to keep `find` running but suppress its further output, then the easiest solution I can think of is to use `bg ; disown ; exit`. That will stop the shell from killing its child process (`find`) and exit the shell; assuming it's at the top level of the Terminal window, you'll see a bit more output and `find` will keep running (but you'll have no way to interact with it).

Comment: Can you clarify the sentence "Redirecting the job's standard output is unrelated."?

Comment: Sure.  The main effect of backgrounding a process is that your *input* (including signals, like ^Z) no longer interact with that process; they interact with the parent shell instead.  Unless the process is written to check if it's in the background and do something different, output will still emanate from that process.

Comment: You could even skip the `fg` step and directly use `kill %` (maybe giving it `-INT` or `-QUIT` if desired, and changing to `%1` or other depending on what other jobs are running, see `jobs` output for details).

Answer (score 6):

I use disown.

```
find / & disown
exit # close the terminal and the command still runs
```

You can use disown after you ^Z as well:

```
find /
^Z
bg
disown
exit
```

disown is a bash builtin, I believe. Not sure about alternatives for other shells.

For further information, see [my equivalent answer on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/311593/keeping-a-linux-process-running-after-i-logout/311737#311737).

Answer (score 5):

You can set the operation to a different key with stty on any UNIX-like system.

```
$ stty susp Q
```

will make Q your suspend key in place of CTRL-Z.

Comment: That's brillant! Now you cannot use the Q key for what $DEITY intended ("Q").

Comment: You don't *have* to use Q, Pax.

Answer (score 5):

Backgrounding a process will not disconnect the output from the terminal device, that's why you're still seeing output and the output may well contain control characters which can stuff up your TTY settings (`cat`ing binary files is a good way to do that).

If you want the job to run in the background, do it right:

```
find / >/tmp/out 2>&1 &
```

then examine the `/tmp/out` file when it's finished.

Comment: Except wouldn't you normally put the 2>&1 before the >/tmp/out? (Mind, I actually don't have any clue, so feel free to ignore.)

Comment: No, @Jeremy, because it's positional. My version directs stdout to the file then stderr to the same place as stdout (the file). Your suggestion would direct stderr to the same place as stdout (the terminal), then stdout to the file. And I rarely ignore questions, I'd rather educate.

Answer (score 2):

I usually do this kind of thing with nohup. Like this:

nohup find / > /tmp/myresults.txt &

nohup makes sure that the process doesn't stop, even if the console goes away (like, you close the window or lose your SSH or whatever). The ">" sends output to a file rather than to the console, and "&" puts the job in the background.

Comment: An idea just occcured to me from the nohup: "to use it with screen command" like "nohup screen". It may be helpful. +1 for sharing your experience

Comment: Why would you use screen with nohup? screen has a detach function built-in. (C-a, C-d)

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you're using a common variant of Linux or UNIX and possibly the bash shell.  In which case:

CTRL-Z sends the `SIGTSTP` signal to the foreground process.  You should be able to do the same thing with the kill command by specifying `kill -s SIGTSTP [pid]`.

Answer (score 1):

kill -STOP your_pid_here

from another console window?

http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2007/11/23/how-to-pause-a-linux-process/#comment-132413

Answer (score 0):

I know that in Ubuntu 9.04, you can start the process with a & after it to run it in the background. For example, "sudo gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst &" will start a text editor editing the GRUB config file in the background.